# Referencing image files in markdown for flask app

Tags: flask, markdown, jinja2, flask-flatpages

I am trying to create a simple blog app using flask that uses flask_flatpages to fill a jinja2 template using the contents of a markdown file for each post.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')
pages = FlatPages(app)

@app.route('/<path>/')
def blog_post(path):
    post = pages.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to link an image in the markdown file, for example the following example_post.md file returns a 404 error in the rendered HTML for the image.png file (when accessing e.g. http://localhost:5000/example_post/)

```
# Heading
Here is an example image.
![png](image.png)
```

I think this is because accessing the image attempts to find `example_post/image.png`, due to the route I created, but the image is actually in the same directory as the `post.md` file (there is no `example_post/` directory). The file structure is as follows:

```
--app.py
--posts/
----example_post.md
----image.png
--templates/
----post.html
```

Any suggestions for how to correctly reference the image.png file in this case, or how to better structure the app to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

We can use this below as an example to fix your problem.

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir, 'md'), filename)
```

Example :
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/65747/flask.send_from_directory